# Wrap the first word in span after the last link jQuery

Tags: jquery

Trying to find a way to wrap the first word in a span tag. The text to wrap would always trail the last link

```
 <div class="style1">
    <a class="style2" href="http://www.example.com">a</a>
    <a class="style3" href="http://www.example.com">b</a>
    test test test test test test test 
</div>
```

I'd like the first `test` to be wrapped in `<span>test</span>`

It would be used in a more in depth solution here

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evanmoore/awwTA/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.pag').contents().filter(function () {
  // IE doesn't support `textContent` proerty, you can replace it with $(this).text()
  if (this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.textContent) !== '') {
      $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().html(function (i, v) {
           return v.replace(/(\w+\s)/, '<span>$1</span>')
      }).replaceWith(function() {
           return this.innerHTML;
      })
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XKjtq/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I combined it with this script, but when I do it I'm seeing both results at the same time. http://jsfiddle.net/evanmoore/36Wwt/1/

Comment: yes. that's it. thank u. why are the selected boxes a little thicker?

Comment: hmm... the 7, that's selected, seems to have an extra space to its right. the 5 that's selected seems to as well. i inspected the element and its white space.

Comment: well, it turns out when a pagination is selected, it has two hard coded &nsbp; wrapped around it and it looks like this when i render the code. i added the spaces to the number '5' on the html section http://jsfiddle.net/evanmoore/9AMnU/1/ is there an expression to kill and select the pagination?

Comment: @Evan Sorry, you should post another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bit of code:

```
<script>
    data = $(".style1").html().trim().split("\n");
    str = data[data.length - 1];
    data.splice(data.length - 1, 1);
    str = str.trim().split(" ");
    str[0] = "<span>" + str[0] + "</span>";
    data[data.length] = str.join(" ");
    $(".style1").html(data.join("\n"));
</script>
```